# Strange calculation

Tags: c++, numbers

I can't understand why does my program do such calculations:

```
#define PixelsPerMeter 40.0

// 40 pixels ~ 1 meter
#define Meters2Pixels(meters) (float)meters*PixelsPerMeter
#define Pixels2Meters(pixels) (float)pixels/PixelsPerMeter

// The speed of free falling
#define G Meters2Pixels(9.81)

// ...
float mHeight = 768;
float _windPower = Meters2Pixels(-5.0);
// ...

float x1 = ( mHeight / G ) * _windPower;

cout << "G: " << G << "; wind: " << _windPower << "\n";
cout << "Height: " << mHeight << "\n";
cout << "Calculating: " << mHeight / G * _windPower << "\n";

=>
G: 392.4; wind: -200
Height: 768
Calculating: -626300
```

I can't understand why... If I calculate this by hands, for example, I have to get: 
**-391.4**

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enclose the macro expansions in parenthesis as:

```
#define Meters2Pixels(meters) ((float)meters*PixelsPerMeter)
#define Pixels2Meters(pixels) ((float)pixels/PixelsPerMeter)
```

The C/C++ preprocessor does a blind substitution. Without the parenthesis, `x1` will be computed as:

```
float x1 = ( mHeight / (float)9.81*40.0 ) * _windPower;
```

which divides `mHeight` by `9.81` and then multiplies the result with `40.0`. Which is not you want. You want `mHeight` to be divided by the product of `9.81` and `40.0` hence the parenthesis.

you can always see how your macros get expanded before your file goes for compilation by using the `-E` option of `g++` as:

```
g++ -Wall -E myfile.cpp
```

**EDIT:**

Its also best to enclose the macro parameter in parenthesis as well, this will guard you if you pass an expression ( like say `Meters2Pixels(foo + 2)`:

```
#define Meters2Pixels(meters) ((float)(meters)*PixelsPerMeter)
#define Pixels2Meters(pixels) ((float)(pixels)/PixelsPerMeter)
```

Comment: I'd also recommend enclosing the macro arguments in parenthesis as well, in case you pass in a value that changes your operator precedence to something undesirable.

Comment: Macros aren't evil, but I don't think this is a great use case.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid trouble with macros, you should consider using inline functions.